# How to host nop commerce 2.65 on IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, nopcommerce

I downloaded nopCommerce 2.65. Can anyone tell me the procedures to host that website on IIS on Win7?

Answer (score 2):

Nopcommerce has a deploy script in the root folder. Execute this script and it will create a 'deployable' folder. From there all you need to do is create a site in IIS and move the deployable files to the site's virtual directory

Comment: Also, make sure the AppPool user has write access to /bin, /Content,/Plugins, /Global.asax, and the web.config.